# How to prevent word to break into a newline on pressing enter in middle of a word?

Tags: html, css, textbox, whitespace

I have been facing a rare issue only in IE and Edge.
In my application, there is a input textbox. On typing a sentence or even a word, if I press enter in the middle of my word, it not only submits the form, but also breaks the word at that point.
It looks like a new line getting appended, but that is not the case.

Following are the solutins I have tried, but with no result:
1) Restricting the text box to a single line box
2) Overriding the onkeypress function
3) CSS tweaks with white-space, word-wrap, word-break (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/)

Anyone has faced this issue before, and has any insights?

```
 HTML
    <input tabindex="5" type="search" id="searchTextbox" placeholder="search" ng-model="model.searchText" ng-change="populateSearchSuggestion()" key-trap="search" searchval="model.searchText" key-function="setSearchText()">


CSS
.item-search-box {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  height: 70px;
  border-left: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
  padding: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 0; }
  @media screen and (min-width: 1650px) {
    .item-search-box {
      width: 80%; } }
  .item-search-box i {
    display: block;
    font-size: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    left: 20px;
    opacity: 0.8; }
  .item-search-box input[type="search"] {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    border: none;
    height: 45px;
    padding: 0 0 3px 40px;
    font-size: 18px;
    background: transparent;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    border: solid 1px #e7e7e7;
        /*border-radius: $bradius; */ }
    .item-search-box input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
      color: #cccccc; }
    .item-search-box input[type="search"]::-ms-clear {
      color: #b3b3b3;
      width: 30px;
      cursor: pointer; }
    .item-search-box input[type="search"]::-ms-clear:hover {
      color: #333; }
    .item-search-box input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {
      position: relative;
      right: 20px; }
    .item-search-box {
        white-space: nowrap;
        word-wrap: normal;
        word-break: keep-all;
    }
```

Comment: Is it a `<textarea>` or `<input type="text" />`?

Comment: Does it pass along the submit input's value? or does it send it through as blank?

Comment: @ether - It passes the submit input's value as is, even though it looks like a new line has been appended

Comment: @rblarsen - it is <input type="search"/>

Comment: You should edit the question and add the code rather than pasting it in the comments!